# How to deploy a gSOAP Web Service in Ubuntu?

Tags: web-services, ubuntu, cgi, web-deployment, gsoap

I have a doubt concerning the deployment of a Web Service in Ubuntu. It was implemented using gSOAP and it should be deployed, e.g. be accessible from websites (which are developed in e.g. ASP .NET).

I got confused with the whole CGI, Ubuntu, Apache topics. Until now I was able to implement a Web Service in ASP .NET and deploy it on Microsoft ISS. Other than that I can also access a gSOAP Web Service described in a WSDL, using ASP .NET

What are the steps to deploy my own Web Service? I have some more specific questions:

> 1. Do I have to compile the WS as CGI?
> 2. Do I have to install Apache in Ubuntu or the service is already enabled?
> 3. In which particuar directory do I have to place the generated code from the WS compilation ("CGI" I guess)?

I am quite a newbie with regard to gSOAP and the whole "Web Service world", especially in Ubuntu...

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 8):

> Do I have to compile the WS as CGI?
>   Do I have to install Apache in Ubuntu or the service is already enabled?

No, gSoap doesn't need Apache, gSoap implements a [standalone server](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc7.2.3). The [gSoap documentation](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc1.3) recommends not to use CGI because it's stateless and slow. Instead you should use the standalone server or the gSoap Apache modules included in the package. I use gSoap as standalone service with Debian. Therefore I did following (summarized):

1. Install gSoap: `apt-get install gSoap`
2. Manually created the header file (e.g. `header.h`)
3. Create the client and server files with `soapcpp2 -I /usr/include/gsoap header.h`
4. Implemented the functions declared in `header.h`

Good luck

Comment: in Debian Wheezy (on RaspberryPi) the location is different. Use the `soapcpp2 -I /usr/share/gsoap/import header.h` instead