# shoud root start the gsoap stand alone server

Tags: web, service, root, gsoap

I have created a Gsoap stand-alone server. I am looking to have 3 versions of the GSoap server on one host machine (one version is to be used for development, another for testing and a final for production). Of course, each will reside on a different port.

I also saw this link:
[How to deploy a gSOAP Web Service in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405764/how-to-deploy-a-gsoap-web-service-in-ubuntu)

I am wondering which user should start the server - should it be root or some other user?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You need root for ports 80 and 443 and some other ports that are system dependent (some ports are already reserved by other processes). You do not need to run the server as root for higher ports such as 8080.

To create a production-quality service, you should consider using the [Apache module](https://www.genivia.com/doc/apache/html/index.html) or [ISAPI extension](https://www.genivia.com/doc/isapi/html/index.html) for gSOAP.

You can easily create a [stand-alone server](https://www.genivia.com/dev.html#server-cpp) with gSOAP, but if your code in the back-end part of the service (not the gSOAP code) is not 100% robust then, well ...

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have already switched to CXF, JSON and REST using Java, Eclipse, Maven, Hibernate and Spring. Its all working pretty good so far. Quite honestly, I am glad that I no longer have to use the gSoap product. Perhaps your answer will help someone else in the future.

Comment: I chose REST over SOAP for the reasons mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences

Comment: The front-end is to use Android / IPhone - need something that would work fast. Your loyalty to SOAP is just that - finally, there is an abundance of information on the use of REST. Very easy to work with.

Comment: I chuckle when I hear "REST is very easy to work with". By definition *REST = HTTP header + payload* and *SOAP = REST* where *payload = envelop(XML)*. Also, SOAP is not slow by any means: as fast as REST with JSON (at least in C/C++). I agree that from an implementation point of view it is easier to get something working with JSON. The trouble  starts when trying to scale up and make it all work without schemas or high-performance schema-driven parsers. I spoke with many developers spending time to fix data issues with JSON or use the slow and intrinsically non-scalable JSON schema validators.

Comment: "Also, SOAP is not slow by any means: as fast as REST" - if you could note some published benchmarks stating that SOAP is faster (or is as fast) as REST, that would be of tremendous use. Tossing in some projects (examples) whereby SOAP is being used with iOS/Android would be even better.

Comment: See e.g. https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1188581 http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/papers/soapBench2.pdf http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/ISWSpaper.pdf several years ago this was a **hot topic** with many publications in supercomputing conferences and journals, with methods aiming to accelerate XML over TCP/IP and HTTP stacks. The fastest stacks (including gSOAP) get SOAP/XML performance comparable to pushing simple text over HTTP. A Web services/SOAP/REST performance bottleneck is typically application back-end processing cost/latency, not XML/SOAP parsing (or JSON parsing).